# Finding most commonly edited files in subversion

Tags: svn

I'm trying to figure out which files get edited the most frequently. Is there a way to do this in Subversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[StatsSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/) can give you some information about your repositories.

Comment: The most recent version of StatsSVN (from 2010) seems to support a very old version of Subversion (svn.exe) only. So this tool can only be used if the old version of svn is reinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SVNStat](http://svnstat.sourceforge.net/) project at sourceforge. It provides you with many reports on your repository.

Answer (score 0):

There are many needed queries that SVN does not have a direct support. But you may write a very simple program by means of [SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/) to do the job for you. As an example, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335614/how-to-export-changed-files-between-two-svn-revisions/7400560#7400560) and its accepted answer. It may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

svn log -v | grep <strike>"http|svn"</strike>| sort |uniq| head -n

N is number of TOP-files

Edit: pattern for files must be defined, I was totally wrong